# Web components nested slots

Tags: web-component, shadow-dom, custom-element, native-web-component

Is there a better way to pass slots to deeply nested components?

index.html

```html
  <outer-comp>
    <span slot=foo>Lorem ipsum</span>
  </outer-comp>
```

outer component:

```html
  <inner-comp>
    <slot name=foo slot=foo></slot>
  </inner-comp>
```

inner component:

```html
  <slot name=foo></slot>
```

Comment: You could always pass in simple data through Attributes or properties. Can you show a more real example of what you are doing, including the complexity of what you want in the slots.

Comment: I wanted to pass all named slots through a proxy component, automatically inserting <slot id=x slot=x></slot> in the proxy, for each slot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That works just fine :)

```js
class ElOuter extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }
  
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <p>- outer start</p>
      <el-inner>
        <slot name="heading" slot="header"></slot>
      </el-inner>
      <slot></slot>
      <p>- outer stop</p>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('el-outer', ElOuter);

class ElInner extends ElOuter {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
      <p>-- inner start</p>
      <slot name="header"></slot>
      <p>-- inner stop</p>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('el-inner', ElInner);
```

```html
<el-outer>
  <h2 slot="heading">hey</h2>
  <p>I will be in the default content</p>
</el-outer>
```

Comment: Yes, that's the way. I was thinking about multiple named slots, passed to the inner component, without typing `<slot slot=headline name=headline></slot>`, but there is no use for it...

Comment: I was having problem even to declare that i needed this explanation. thank you.